# Unix : Optimized command for subsituting words in large file

Tags: bash, unix

This question is not related to any code issue. Just need your suggestions.

We have a file which is **~ 100GB** and we are applying **sed** to substitute a few parameters.
This process is taking long time and eating up CPU as well

Can the replacement of **sed** with **awk/tr/perl or any other unix utilities** will help in this scenario.

**Note:**

Any suggestion other than *time* command.

Comment: What kind of substitution do you do? Do you know the line number in the file?

Comment: Intuitively, the simpler the better. By this reasoning, if you can't use `tr` - which is even simpler, since it doesn't examine context at all; it replaces all occurrences of the characters you give it - use `sed`. However, it would not be unheard of for Perl or Awk to be a lot quicker, if you hit a sweet spot they can optimize. Measure and compare.

Comment: This is assuming your current script doesn't contain obvious mistakes, such as multiple `sed` invocations where one would suffice. Maybe post a snippet?

Comment: @tripleee Actually sed command is called inside a loop ... nd it performs the substitution for multiple files (4 files) .. each ~100 GB ... so just wanted to know if sed is the right solution to perform such activity ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a couple of things to speed it up:

- use fixed pattern matching instead of regexes wherever you can
- run sed for example as `LANG=C sed '...'`

These two are likely to help a lot. Anything else will lead to just minor improvements, even different tools.

About `LANG=C` - normally the matching is done in whatever encoding your environment is set to which can likely be `UTF-8` which causes additional lookups of the UTF-8 characters. If your patterns use just ascii, then definitely go for LANG=C.

Other things that you can try:

- if you have to use regexes then use the longest fixed character strings you can - this will allow the regex engine to skip non-matching parts of the file faster (it will skip bigger chunks)
- avoid line by line processing if possible - the regex engine will not have to spend time looking for the newline character

Comment: About `LANG=C`, normally the matching is done in whatever encoding your environment is set to (which might be UTF-8 with a certain probability, but might just as well be something different like ISO-8859).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, improved the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try different AWK's:  [mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/mawk.html) has been particularly fast for me.